# How do I disassemble Transcend StoreJet 25A3 external hard disk?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a portable hard disk that is from Transcend, and I want to use that hard disk inside my laptop. But I am stuck at opening the disassembling the hard disk from the case. I removed the only screw, but now I do not know how to open it. I have searched all over the net for tutorials/manuals, but none was of help. Anyone please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the post you put on [Computing.net](http://www.computing.net/answers/hardware/how-do-i-open-disassemble-transcend-storejet-25a3-hard-disk/88012.html), all I could find were the factory manuals.

From what I can see from the information on the [Transcend site](http://www.transcend-info.com), it appears to be a sealed case. Therefore, you will likely have to force (pry) the case open. In doing so, it is highly probable you will destroy the enclosure when doing so. If you are willing to sacrifice the enclosure, just be careful not to damage the drive trying to open the case.

Comment: Yeah it was hard. A lot of clips were there to conceal the box, but managed to open that at last with a thin metal object. No harm done! By the way, thanks for the reply!